# How can I retrieve the data which is unreadable in this database?

Tags: dbf

This is the database:
http://s16.postimg.org/vbmak2yv9/quora.png

I want to have the text which is contained in Question and Answer.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please show some effort, e.g. some code you already wrote to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: Looks like it's been encrypted.

Comment: I didn't written any code because I have no idea. I tried to decode it with base64. Anybody would have a look at the databse? http://www11.zippyshare.com/v/dLSkmDr8/file.html

Comment: OpenOffice or LibreOffice will open that dbf file correctly.